# How to work with reverse and split in a select in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I found the below query very useful for an application I'm working on. However, I wanna replace the values for a select in a table.

```
WITH data AS
(
    select Value, REVERSE(Value) AS ReverseValue from (values
        ('texttext/21/812/21a'), ('texttext/6/163/38a'), ('texttext/53/7a/a2'), ('text/t/e/xt/53/7a/a2')
    )t(Value)
), split AS
(
    select 
        Value, ReverseValue, 
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, 1, P1.Pos - 1)) AS Forth,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1)) AS Third,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1)) AS Second,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, p3.Pos + 1, len(ReverseValue))) AS First
    from data       
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue))) as P1(Pos)
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
)
select Value, First + '-' + Forth + Third + Second AS NewValue from split
```

So instead of `(values ('texttext/21/812/21a') (...)` i want something like `(select myfield from myutable)`. Any ideas of how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the values in the first CTE:

```
WITH data AS (
    select myfield, REVERSE(myfield) AS ReverseValue
    from mytable
   ),
   . . .
```